# SonarQube: Fail to decompress and deserialize source data

Tags: sonarqube

I guess the following errors on a few of my projects. I am running on v5.6.6 but was already seeing this in v5.6.2. Any ideas? Thanks.

`2017.05.02 13:49:40 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task...
org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException: Visit failed for Component {key=....java,type=FILE}  located ...(type=DIRECTORY)->...:...(type=MODULE)->...:...(type=PROJECT)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to decompress and deserialize source data [id=27104,fileUuid=AVM4Z-nfP_ZhzM4w43IO,projectUuid=AVM3bHlalhabhQ4SKhnG]
    at org.sonar.db.source.FileSourceDto.decodeSourceData(FileSourceDto.java:101) ~[sonar-db-5.6.6.jar:na]
[...]
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Stream ended prematurely
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbFileSources$Line.(DbFileSources.java:404) ~[sonar-db-5.6.6.jar:na]
[...]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
2017.05.02 13:49:40 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=...:... | type=REPORT | id=AVvJNTiOQmF-hMBhZB81 | submitter=teamcity | time=3324ms`

Comment: Does error always occur on the same files ?

Comment: Yes, it does occur on the same files.

Comment: Can you please execute the SQL request `select length(binary_data), line_hashes, data_hash from file_sources
where file_uuid = 'AVM4Z-nfP_ZhzM4w43IO'` ? You can safely share the results, they don't contain your sources.

Comment: "too long by 53994 characters" for stackoverflow. :-( 
length |           line_hashes            |            data_hash
--------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------
  64512 | 523048e7f5ca9550505f2d8ea6d587e7+| 5da84ed08e9c317678f716a572096af5
        | cdd366d8530b901f5185a746f419676e+|
[ ... trimmed over 1k rows...]
        | cbb184dd8e05c9709e5dcaedaa0495cf+|
        |                                 +|
        | bdd35c                           |
    680 |                                  |
(2 rows)